# Reference a Variable From Query of Query

Tags: php, laravel

I have this on my controller:

```
$results = Model::where('foreign_id', $id)->get();
```

The result is:

```
Collection {#111 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Model {#112 ▶}
    1 => Model {#113 ▶}
    2 => Model {#114 ▶}
  ]
}
```

However, I need to access the `$results` further with these:

```
$role_A = $results->where('role_id', 1);
$role_B = $results->where('role_id', 2);
$role_C = $results->where('role_id', 3);
```

My problem is that I am having a error if I reference them via:

```
$user_A = $role_A->created_at;
$user_B = $role_B->created_at;
$user_C = $role_C->created_at;
```

I still need include their index position like so:

```
$user_A = $role_A[1]->created_at;
```

My problem is that cannot know the index position for me to reference them, for example, `$user_A` can be any of this below.

```
$user_A = $role_A[0]->created_at;
$user_A = $role_A[1]->created_at;
$user_A = $role_A[2]->created_at;
```

Is there any way where I can reference a variable from a query of query more efficiently?

Comment: Try to add `->first()` like this `$role_A = $results->where('role_id', 1)->first();`

Comment: I can't understand what your problem is, how many results `$role_A = $results->where('role_id', 1);` do you want to retrieve?

Comment: check contains(); https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains if you want to check for exist in collection of objects

Comment: @Takachi - that solved it. thank you very much! you can make an answer for me to accept =)

Comment: @kapitan Done, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get a collection everytime and not a QueryBuilder.

For example, do something like this

```
$role_A = $results->where('role_id', 1)->first();
$role_B = $results->where('role_id', 2)->first();
$role_C = $results->where('role_id', 3)->first();
```

to get what you want as a collection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter) your collection based on the `role_id`

for a `role_id` of 2 you do

```
$results = $results->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value->role_id == 2;
});
```

or add the where directly in the first query

```
$results = Model::where('foreign_id', $id)->where('role_id', 1)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `first`

```
$role_A = $results->where('role_id', 1)->first();
```